# Possible population levels in a Kardashev Type 2 Scale civilization

Tags: internal-consistency, society, space-colonization, space-constructs, far-future

Acording to Futuretimeline a type 2 Kardashev society could be achieved around the year 3100 when science is advanced enough to allow the creation of a Dyson Sphere and due to its size it could house many trillions of people perhaps quadrillions of people. However aside from the creations of sentient robots and androids or races created using Synthetic Biology trends indicate that the worçld population will level off by the end of this century and begin to decline a bit afterwards.

The basic objective of a Dyson Sphere is to harvest all the solar energy from ts light however it could have secondary objectives like house and enormous population growth that could happen in the next millenium. But I cannot see why the population would grow so much but it sis possible that after 2100 the world population will decline for a few centuries and after that raise again but I am pretty sure that natural reproduction and "natural" people obviously will not cause such population growth. Robots, androids, replicants or other artifitial kinds of sentience would make the world population raise a lot considering that they could be be created much faster than a human who needs 8/9 months of gestation and spetial needs as a baby.

Given the technological advances and the feasibility of a Dyson Sphere in a Kardashev Scale 2 civilization how much bigger could the entire civilization be compared to now?

Below is the FutureTimeline post:

3100 AD

Humanity is becoming a Type 2 civilisation on the Kardashev scale

The ongoing growth of AI has allowed the manipulation of matter on scales barely dreamed of before. The largest structure now being constructed in space is a Dyson Sphere.* This hollow shell is of such gargantuan proportions that it fully encloses the Sun, capturing all of its solar energy output.

Under the direction of a Godlike superintelligence, vast swarms of automated, self-replicating ships are building it, using material from various asteroid fields and regions further beyond such as the Kuiper Belt and Oort Cloud. The sphere can harvest some 386 yottajoules (YJ) per second.*

The interior walls have a gravitational field of 1G and are made from wholly new states of matter that were unknown to science in previous centuries. These can withstand the colossal tensile forces required to maintain structural integrity. This curved, impossibly large surface – equivalent to many millions of planet Earths – is becoming a habitat for many sentient lifeforms, with portions being terraformed and given stable atmospheres, oceans and landmasses. A sizeable percentage of citizens are now migrating to these strange artificial worlds. This includes a diverse mix of biological humans, as well as transhumans, synthetics, clones, androids, sentient animals and other communities. A series of additional Dyson Spheres are being constructed around neighbouring star systems – some even larger.

Having begun its journey to the stars in the 22nd century, humanity is reaching a landmark in its exploration of space. A region nearly 1,000 light years in radius has now been settled (or about 2 percent of the total length of our galaxy).

[enter link description here](https://www.futuretimeline.net/the-far-future-3000-9999.htm)

Comment: Somewhat depends on lots of factors. Given that the Earth might be able to stretch to [over 30 trillion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/19442/55743) population if you engineer it right, even this solar system alone might stretch to the quadrillions. Could you give us a bit more info of what sort of answer you're expecting.

Comment: My understanding about lower future population projections is simply due to parents focusing their resources more tightly upon fewer children. It's a choice that makes sense once you can be fairly confident those children will survive. When child mortality was high it made sense to have more children but not focus so much on any particular child.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir conversely, some people would like larger families but for financial or medical reasons they're quite unable to do so.

Comment: But back to the question: minus all the fluff, is it simply "_how many people could live on the inside surface of a magic dyson sphere that has gravity?_"

Comment: VTC: Given the magic gravity and godlike AI, the question reduces to "what size population does the AI want", which is story-based, rather than worldbuilding.,

Comment: Please ask a specific question. At the moment it just sounds like "I wonder what the population would be like." For example a question is " The dyson sphere can contain sixty quadrillion people. But why would a post-scarcity society that looks like blah blah blah want to grow to that population?"

Comment: Why would you want to build a Dyson ball in the first place?

Comment: You say that "trends indicate that the world population will level off by the end of the century" but you don't get into the real reasons why people are predicting this. Especially relevant is whether these reasons would still be true if we were advanced enough to build this kind of creation. So I challenge your assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

### Upper Bounds

Our constraints are :

- Custom matter can be produced trivially
- Population can be digital or biological
- Megastructures are possible
- 1,000 light years

So, it seems we have two ways of looking at the population limit : volume and power.

### Power

I think power is going to be the limiting case, so I'll go there first.

The [typical human goes through](https://www.fao.org/3/y5686e/y5686e08.htm) 2,500 ${kcal}\over{day}$, or about ten megajoules per day (10 ${MJ}\over{day}$). Current technology AI "brains" actually perform much worse on an energy consumption level, so we could consider 10 ${MJ}\over{day}$ to be "future tech" efficiency (there exist algorithms to compute the hard limit -- but I have only glanced them, so we'll use this approximation instead).

[This estimate](https://www.quora.com/How-many-stars-are-there-within-1-000-light-years-from-our-Solar-System) provides that there are 3.2 million stars within 1,000 light years. According to [this estimate](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-mass-of-a-star), the frequency-adjusted average star mass is 0.36 solar masses. The sun's mass being about $2 \times 10^{30}$ kilograms, we can compute the total energy available to your sci-fi star empire. The mass of planets and "stuff" around the star is not trivial, but will be neglected for now.

$E = (3.2 \times 10^6) (0.36) (2 \times 10^{30}) c^2$ = $2.07 \times 10^{53}$ joules.

Since each "citizen" needs 10 MJ ($1 \times 10^6$ joules) per day, and we'll assume perfect recycling so that power is available tomorrow as well -- you have a maximum population bound of $(2.07 \times 10^{53}) \div (1 \times 10^6) = 2 \times 10^{47}$.

Or, 0.2 trillion + trillion + trillion + trillion

### Space

Let's say each citizen is allocated a budget of one cubic meter of personal space (on average). How many cubic meters are there in 1,000 light years?

Per [this reference](https://www.metric-conversions.org/length/lightyears-to-meters.htm), there are $9.4 \times 10^{15}$ meters per light year.

So, 1,000 light years is $9.4 \times 10^{18}$ meters.

And a cube, 1,000 light years on a side is $(9.4 \times 10^{18})^3 = 8.3 \times 10^{56}$ or

0.8 billion + trillion + trillion + trillion + trillion

### Summary

Between $2 \times 10^{47}$ and $8.3 \times 10^{56}$ citizens

Answer (score 0):

2 percent growth per year is a reasonable number, in a setting where resources are more available. Reasons for current growth dynamic are a bit complicated, and there are many social factors which are debatable, but the rate of growth from 1900's to 2000's is an observable fact, and is within natural limits easily.

With such a growth rate population can be bigger than it is as of today in about 400'000'000 times in a thousand years. So 400 millon trillions can be a reasonable number.

Humans produced with artificial wombs, I would not call them any different than other humans, same way as chuckes are chickens. But it may be annoying to pay attencion to more than 5 kids in average, so even if wuch solution is common and present number not necessarly drastically bigger, but it definetly a potencial to have a rapid growth if there is a need for that.

With K2 resources on this time scale are not a limiting factor, and being this way it also can be exactly a reason (one of) for growth rates higher than 2% per year, even without other means. More so, become much bigger and faster than today may be a solution for shortage of skilled work force.(this directon is quite deep rabbit hole, there are reasons due complexity of technological knowledge we have to work with and such)

As side note that futusomething piece of text is quite optimistic by nature, but low quality, 2/10, would not rely on it that much for anything. K2 can be achieved much sooner, and in a more proper way, and in this way K2 can be a resource available for trillions of people, and few trillions of people can be adequate number for it, at some point and with future growth, as there are certain benefits in increasing number of people, mainly in processing information and controlling the situation.

Comment: Artificial wombs won't reverse the fertility decline of western civilization. While it's possible that some dystopian regimes would attempt to raise humans as livestock in bulk, there will be little enthusiasm for it otherwise.